# Any way to except empty field from $request->all() in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.6

I want to except empty value field from `$request->all();`

> **Array ( [first_name] => Dev 1 [password] => [last_name] => [phone] => 123456 [password_confirmation] => )**

I got the array like this but I want to except field from above array like last_name, password which has no value.

Any way to do this without for loop. 
I mean **`laravel`** provide any default method for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will remove empty elements:

```
$filtered = array_filter($request->all());
```

Comment: That's a great answer.